# Is there any way to get the last 10 object of an observable array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, ngrx

I'm using `ngrx` entity adapter `selectAll`. and it returns an observable list of type Object (event).
I want to get only the last 10 Objects of it .
this is my selector

```
const geteventsFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<EventState>(
  "events"
);

export const getEvents = createSelector(
  geteventsFeatureState,
  eventAdapter.getSelectors().selectAll
);

export const getEventLoading = createSelector(
  geteventsFeatureState,
  (state: EventState) => state.loading
);

export const getEventLoaded = createSelector(
  geteventsFeatureState,
  (state: EventState) => state.loaded
);

export const getError = createSelector(
  geteventsFeatureState,
  (state: EventState) => state.error
);
```

this is my component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.event$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromEvent.getEvents));
}
```

it's already returns all my Object and I want to select the last 10  items
Anyone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selectors with props to get data based on some external conditions.In the selector we can pass props to the selector function like this:

**selector.ts**

```
  export const getLastEvents = createSelector(
      getCounterValue,
      (events, props) => events.slice(Math.max(events.length - props, 1))
    );
```

In component you can pass props to select method to get last 10 data.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.event$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromEvent.getLastEvents,10));
}
```